# How to nest two loops for two files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing code to read two text files and print output for each line in first file with all lines on file 2

```
try:
    with open("file1.txt", "r") as ins , open("file2.txt", "r") as ins2 :

        array = []
        for line in ins:
        #print(line)
        # Start inner for
            for line2 in ins2:

                print(line + " : " + line2)


except IOError as e:
    print 'Operation failed: %s' % e.strerror
```

file 1 content samples :

```
text1
text2
text3
```

file 2 content sample :

```
1985
1986
1987
```

output must be

```
text1 :1985
text1 :1986
text1 :1987
text2 :1985
text2 :1986
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: You can check https://gist.github.com/hygull/a2d5fb226a60b16b946196b554108ff4, it is the solution  for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, its work with me fine.

Comment: Great. Thank you.